# Use LinearColorMapper in Bokeh high-level charts

Tags: python, charts, bokeh

Is there any way to use `LinearColorMapper` in Bokeh high-level charts ?

I'd like to generate a `ScatterChart` ; I know that I can use `color` and `palette` constructor parameters, but I need to map given colours for given range, which those two parameters cannot guarantee.

To be more precise, I've got a set of download speed record. Knowing the theoretical download speed of the line, I'd like to present those records in that way : green if the speed is superior to `1.5 × theoretical_speed`, red if the speed is inferior to `0.5 × theoretical_speed` ; between those limits, I need a linear gradient.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[This example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/color_scatter.py) should prove helpful to you.

LinearColorMapper seems to work well on some levels - plotting a figure, but I had trouble using it for Circle fill_color.  The Texas Unemployment example in the gallery I found deceptively complicated.

I did find that mapping it myself with Python was pretty easy - [as Peter suggests here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/r9oIF00rDF8)

**Note that palettes are just lists of hex color strings.**

I was able to use some control flow to create a proper list of colors to add to my ColumnDataSource and then to the fill_color property of my circles.  It sounds like you could do something similar and/or adapt the first example above to your needs.